# Clojure zip function

Tags: clojure, standard-library, sequences

I need to build a seq of seqs (vec of vecs) by combining first, second, etc elements of the given seqs.

After a quick searching and looking at [the cheat sheet](http://clojure.org/cheatsheet). I haven't found one and finished with writing my own:

```
(defn zip 
  "From the sequence of sequences return a another sequence of sequenses
  where first result sequense consist of first elements of input sequences
  second element consist of second elements of input sequenses etc.

  Example:

  [[:a 0 \\a] [:b 1 \\b] [:c 2 \\c]] => ([:a :b :c] [0 1 2] [\\a \\b \\c])"
  [coll]
  (let [num-elems (count (first coll))
        inits (for [_ (range num-elems)] [])]
    (reduce (fn [cols elems] (map-indexed
                              (fn [idx coll] (conj coll (elems idx))) cols))
        inits coll)))
```

I'm interested if there is a standard method for this?

Comment: This function is usually called `zip`, not `unzip`; using this unconventional name may have made it harder for you to find the existing implementations.

Comment: Yes you're probably right, I've updated the name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(apply map vector [[:a 0 \a] [:b 1 \b] [:c 2 \c]])
;; ([:a :b :c] [0 1 2] [\a \b \c])
```

You can use the variable arity of `map` to accomplish this.

From the `map` docstring:

> ... Returns a lazy sequence consisting of the result of applying f to
>   the set of **first** items of each coll, followed by applying f to the set
>   of **second** items in each coll, until any one of the colls is exhausted.
>   Any remaining items in other colls are ignored....

Comment: Isn't very obvious. Works like a charm. =) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Kyle's solution is a great one and I see no reason why not to use it, but if you want to write such a function from scratch you could write something like the following:

```
(defn zip 
  ([ret s]
    (let [a (map first s)]
      (if (every? nil? a)
        ret
        (recur (conj ret a) (map rest s)))))
  ([s]
    (reverse (zip nil s))))
```